# Text and a form not centered under a certain width of window

Tags: html, css

I am implementing a responsive html page. I cannot reproduce the case on fiddle, so I published the page on "www.000webhost". Here is the link : https://test1flamant.000webhostapp.com/. Please use it on Firefox and let me know if this link does not work

The issue is that the text "Find your home" on the first page is not any more centered on the first image under an innerWidth that is approximately 695px. The text, under this limit, remains with a constant left margin.

I have the same issue with the form on the below second image under approximately the same limit.

To help you, I displayed clientWidth and innerWidth at the top of the page. Please don't pay attention to the other details on the page, as I am concentrating only on this issue.

Here is the relevant portion of html portion of code relative to this issue

```
  <div class="homePageImage1" style="background-size:cover;">
    <div class="position2 horizontal-center textAlignCenter lineHeight117 pinyonscriptregular120dieseFFFFFF">
      Find Your Home
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="homePageImage2">
    <div class="position3 horizontal-center"  [formGroup]="searchFormGroup">
      <div class="position4 border2 textAlignCenter backgroundwhite poppinsextrabold14diese372300">
        Search
      </div>
      <span class="position5 width100percent" >
        <input class="floatLeft dimension1 border3 poppinsregular16diese372300" type="text" placeholder="Dans quelle ville ? Quartier ?" formControlName="ville">
        <input class="floatLeft dimension2 border4 poppinsregular16diese372300" type="text" placeholder="Votre budget max" formControlName="prixMax">
        <div class="floatLeft dimension3 textAlignCenter lineHeight48 backgroundPrimary poppinsbold12diese372300">SEARCH</div>
      </span>      
    </div>
    <div  class="position6">
      <a href="javascript:" class="poppinsregular14dieseFFFFFF textdecorationunderline">Advanced search</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the text "Find Your Home" to be always centered, you can first remove the "position: relative" property from the ".homePageImage1" class.

And add the @media rule to enable the property only if the window width is higher than a certain width (I found 1006px on my side).

It will look like :

```
@media (min-width:1006px) {
    .homePageImage1 {
         position: relative;
    }
}
```

So the text will be centered according to the windows under 1006px.

Comment: Thanks pac421, it works for the text "Find your home", but for the form on the second image, if I remove position: relative to ".homePageImage2", the form is placed relative to the ".firstPage" element. How to resolve it ?

Comment: I think the best solution is to combine the CSS "flexbox" and "@media" tools. I created a fiddle to illustrate how they can be used in your case : https://jsfiddle.net/pac421/h0wgo2se/. If you want to learn how to use the CSS flexbox tool, you can look at this complete guide https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#flexbox-background. On my side, I've learned it with this well-made little game https://flexboxfroggy.com/#fr.